# Подключение библиотеки GLPK к проекту Qt

Tags: c++, qt

В своё время скачал и сделал make/install библиотеки [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/), лежит это всё `./Documents/Libraries/glpk`. Был сделан проект на Xcode, где просто прописал include и пути к библиотеке.

Теперь же возникла нужда перенести когда из этого проекта в проект на Qt. Как это сделать пошагово?

В .pro дописал:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /Users/username/Documents/Libraries/glpk-4.65/src/glpk.h
LIBS += -L/Users/username/Documents/Libraries/glpk-4.65 -lglpk
```

В нужном файле делаю импорт:
`#import <glpk.h>`

Однако Qt не видит этот h-файл.

Нужно ли переносить какие-то файлы с установленной библиотекой в папку с проектом Qt? Что ещё прописывать в .pro файле, имеет ли значение, где прописаны эти мантры? 
Реально ли потом, после использования сторонней библиотеки, сделать статическую линковку проекта?

P.s. Может кто знает хорошую библу с методом внутренней точки?

Answer (score 1):

INCLUDEPATH  - это путь к папке. А Вы туда прописали прямо путь с именем файла.

Comment: Попровил. _`glpk.h` file not found_

Comment: если просто так прописать, но при этом не перезапустить qmake, то может какое то время писать, что файла нет. Но при этом иногда может даже не компилироваться - пересборка обычно помогает

Comment: Перезапускал qmake

Comment: скачал либу - там файл glpk.h находится в папке include, а не src. Аккуратно проводником/finder посмотрите, где именно находится файл и скорректируйте путь